# hashcat prints out "clGetPlatformIDs(): CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR"

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, hashcat

I do have a problem with hashcat 4.2.1 prints this "platform not found" message to me every time I try using it, I looked for solutions and for that I tried reinstalling openCL and I think I installed it properly, I do have dell inspiron 15 3537, with i5 4200u and AMD radeon hd 8670m with the drivers that came pre-insralled with my Ubuntu 18.04! can anyone assist me like why would this really happen? what kind of things could be the problem and how to fix it?
I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [hashcat website](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#i_may_have_the_wrong_driver_installed_what_should_i_do) that may help you with your issue. I've had a similar problem like this occur before, and to quickly get the job done I ran the code using `--opencl-device-types 2` to utilize my graphics card to process the command rather than it using my Ryzen 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back though it was not a driver issue (from what I know) what ended up working for me was using `--force` at the end of the command, hopefully that works for you as it did for me.